# How to group records in ranges of their created_at age in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to create a graph to show how long it took to close various deals. The time it takes to close a deal is calculated by the deal's created_at and closed_at timestamps.

I want to group deals into two time ranges: deals which took from 0 to 30 days to close, and deals which took from 31 days to 60 days to close.

I.e. I want a hash like this {"1-30" => 5, "31-60" => 10} where the values are the number of deals of that age range.

Since my model does not have a days_old column, I need to use Postgres to calculate this when i do the grouping.

I've tried the following but I'm getting the error below. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? I'm sure the CASE syntax is correct.

```
sql = <<~SQL
  count(*),
  CASE
    WHEN ABS( DATE_PART('day', created_at - closed_at) ) BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN '0-30'
    WHEN ABS( DATE_PART('day', created_at - closed_at) ) BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN '31-60'
  END AS day_range
SQL

Deal.select(sql).group(:day_range).count

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 6: END AS day_range
```

Comment: can you try the same for test purpose but without groupBy, just display the `case` in a select?

Comment: Why you use `.count` in the end?

Comment: @StevenBENET thanks helping out but it turns out i didnt need the count() method at the end,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `count` in the end, you query should like this

```
Deal.select(sql).group(:day_range)
```

see the example result in [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/692eb/1)

Comment: Ah good catch... dont know why i missed that. Thank you very much!